# VirtualHost not working in Microsoft Edge

Tags: virtual-host, microsoft-edge

I am using Virtual host and its working fine in all browser i am able to access it from all browsers but in windows 10 Microsoft Edge its not working. Its only opening localhost not any other virtual host that i have defined

My Windows Host file contain

```
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       developerquery
::1             developerquery

127.0.0.1       test
::1             test
```

Appache VirutalHost.conf contain

```
NameVirtualHost *:80



<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "F:\Local server\htdocs\localhost"
    CustomLog logs/localhost.error.logs combined
    ErrorLog logs/localhost.error.log
</VirtualHost>    

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName developerquery
    ServerAlias developerquery
    DocumentRoot "F:\Local server\htdocs\developerquery"
    CustomLog logs/developerquery.error.logs combined
    ErrorLog logs/developerquery.error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test
    ServerAlias test
    DocumentRoot "F:\Local server\htdocs\test"
    CustomLog logs/test.error.logs combined
    ErrorLog logs/test.error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 6):

Found a solution here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0face535-3c7a-4658-be34-6c376322ca34/microsoft-edge-cant-open-local-domains?forum=win10itpronetworking.

Basically you need to:

- Go to Control Panel > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet  > Site
- Unchecked "include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other zones" and "Include all sites that bypass the proxy server"
- Click OK and restart Edge